# Android Customized Seekbar Repeating progressDrawable

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

While applying a drawable to the progressDrawable of the seekbar, it repeats itself. Please see below:
[image]

I do not want it to repeat, and just simply stretch.

Code:

> seekbar_background.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/slider_background"
    android:tileMode="disabled" />
```

> slider_background :[image]

Seekbar Code :

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/riskBarInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dealSizeInput"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_background"
                android:thumb="@drawable/slider_knob" />
```

Comment: You should use [9-patch image resource](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

Comment: I loaded the .png into the draw9patch utility, but then what? What do I do to make it stretch?

Comment: please post complete xml file

Comment: I guess the appropriate code is enough for an answer, please help!